# return the same XML Doc structure with specific conditions in XPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, xquery

I have xml document similar to xml in page http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

the problem is how to return this document with elements corresponding to a certain value? how to XPath or XQuery command should be written ?

for example search for title contains 'Learning' then the return xml doc should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

how to get this result?

another question how to search with ignoring characters case, so 'learNING' should return the same result?

Comment: XPath in general does not allow you to create new nodes or new documents, you can only select nodes in existing documents. If you want to create a new document then you need XSLT or XQuery.

Comment: how to solve this in XQyery?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: I get a list of 'book' element with the exact title by executing //book[title[text()='Learning XML']] but that not what i really want, now I am looking how to use contains function and how to ignore characters case, finally how to get the desired result.

Comment: so @cFrozenDeath do you have answer or just wondering what I tried !

Comment: @DevX sorry I just read your last comment. I'm sorry but I will not help you until you show us **the code** that you tried to use. You can read how to do it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: I have asp.net web app and a textbox, I need to get text from it and pass it as string command for xpath or xquery to another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XQuery you can do as follow :

```
<bookstore>
{
    for $d in //book[contains(lower-case(title),'learning')]
    return  $d
}
</bookstore>
```

**<kbd>[`Xpathtester Demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/4439808e449741a8f8486f0ec75868ee)</kbd>**

Notice that there will be only one `<bookstore>` that wraps all matched `<book>` elements returned, and notice the use of `lower-case()` function to 'ignore' character case of the book title in the matching process.

Comment: thank you, this is what i need, one more question about this please, if bookstore element has attributes can I include them?

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> book = doc.Descendants("book").Where(x => x.Element("title").Value.Contains("Learn")).ToList();

            XDocument filteredDoc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><bookstore></bookstore>");
            XElement root = (XElement)filteredDoc.FirstNode;
            root.Add(book);
        }

    }
}​
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I appreciate your answer, linq makes working with XML easier , however, I need to return full doc without child elements that don't match a sample string as written in question, is it possible in Xquery or Xpath or both? the answer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
for $d in doc('books')//book[title[contains(text(),'Beginning')]]
return <bookstore> {$d} </bookstore>
```

However this solution does not handle ignoring character case.

Comment: very close, but this code return multiple <bookstore> element, as a root element it should not be repeated.